# After connecting to RTSP, OpenCV throws 401 error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

The script is just suppose to grab a frame from the RTSP stream and save it every 60 seconds. The block below checks if it is a valid connection. I.e User/Password and IP is correct and in this case to wait if the camera becomes disconnected.

The script connects and saves the frame correctly.

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://user:pass@192.168.1.2/stream/', cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
try:
    if video.isOpened():
        ref, frame = video.read()
        cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % ref, frame)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

However after that it throws a notice

```
[rtsp @ 0000022c41432c0] method DESCRIBE failed: 401 Unauthorized
```

Am I not setting up the device correctly? Or is it possible the device does not support DESCRIBE or is implemented poorly?

Comment: That is not a OpenCV error, I believe its a ffmpeg error. In the past I've received that error due to incorrect login credentials to access the RTSP stream. Check your credentials and try again, also insert the stream link to VLC to verify that your link is working

Comment: That's the catch, I can connect just fine. Snapshot works. Just throws that after.

Comment: Maybe the username or password is not correct. 401 means: **The request was not authorized for authentication or the verification failed.**

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar experience in an environment using hikvision cameras.

When creating/updating your password the interface suggests...

> 8 to 16 characters allowed, including upper-case letters, lower-case letters, digits and special characters (!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ space)

Notice the 16 character upper limit, it will truncate that password so for a quick example

> ThisPasswordWillBeTruncated

Will result in the password being saved as

> ThisPasswordWill

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was just due to wrong password. This must be password set for the user in the camera set-up.

Answer (score 0):

Special characters must be converted to another format
like this:

```
# -> %23
$ -> %24

ex.
    source = 'rtsp://username:1234#$@~~~'
->
    source = 'rtsp://username:1234%23%24@~~~'
```